# How to compare values in arrays and add the value from one array to another

Tags: powershell

I've got 2 arrays:

$array1 = ('1','2','7','9')
$array2 = ('7','9','1','2')

These collections are dynamically changed and I need to add the values from the first array to second. I need to create a condition if.... and check... if these arrays are equals - do nothing.

But, if the first array has new value for example it becomes $array1 = ('1','2','7','9', '6') and second array doesn't have such value

then I need to add this '6' new value to the second array...so the second array will become $array2 = ('7','9','1','2', '6')... please help to achieve it.

Please note that values in 2 arrays could be in different order it doesn't matter, the goal is to have the same values inside 2 arrays.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Is the order of the items in `$array2` important? Otherwise you can just do `$array2 = @($array1;$array2) |Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: I just need to add the unique values from the array1 to array2 so they will become the same, the order is not important..

Answer (score 3):

Merge the two and sort out non-unique values:

```
$array2 = @($array1;$array2) |Sort-Object -Unique
```

---

For large arrays you may want to add all items from both arrays to a HashSet instead - it'll only store distinct values, so the resulting set will correspond to the new value of `$array2`:

```
$set = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[psobject]]::new()
$array1 |% { [void]$set.Add($_) } 
$array2 |% { [void]$set.Add($_) } 

$array2 = @($set)
```

Comment: Clever. It won't matter with the sample input, but note that hash sets (unlike `Sort-Object`) are case-_sensitive_ by default.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retain the order in `$array2` and append those elements (in order) from `$array1` that aren't yet in `$array2`, you can use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object):

```bash
$array1 = '1','2','7','9','6'
$array2 = '7','9','1','2'

$array2 += 
  (Compare-Object -PassThru $array1 $array2 | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq  '<=')
```

Note: `Compare-Object`, like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default; add `-CaseSensitive` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IsSupersetOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.issupersetof?view=net-7.0) and [`UnionWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.unionwith?view=net-7.0) from [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1):

```bash
$array1 = [string[]] ('1','2','7','9','new value')
$array2 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] ('7','9','1','2')

if(-not $array2.IsSupersetOf($array1)) {
    $array2.UnionWith($array1)
}

$array2
```

In case you need to have an actual array back you can cast `[object[]]` or `[string[]]` back depending on your need:

```bash
[string[]] $array2
```

---

Worth mentioning that hashsets are case sensitive by default, in case you need a case-insensitive hashset you can instantiate it using a [case-insensitive comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-6.0):

```bash
$array2 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]]('7','9','1','2'),
    [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build on top of this solution, by creating a function.

This code block lists array 1 and array 2
It uses the `-notcontains` cmdlet to check if the elements in array are in array2 and if not, then appends the element in array 2.

```
$array = @('1','2','7','9', '15') 
$array2 = @('1','2','7','9')

Write-Output "$array `n"

Write-Output "$array2 `n"

$array | ForEach-Object {
    if ($array2 -notcontains $_) {
        $array2 += $_
    }
}

Write-Output "$array2"
```

Hope this helps!